# Snowflake JDBC database metadata not returning getImportedKeys

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, referential-integrity

I have Java code that extracts metadata from a JDBC connection.  One of the calls is to extract the imported keys.  The database has the RI created, but is disabled.  **Is there a way to extract the disabled imported keys?**

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/snowflake-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
    <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.18</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
keys = metadata.getImportedKeys(tableCatalog, tableSchema, tableName);

while (keys.next()) {
    importedTag(docBuff, keys, columnMap);
}
keys.close();
```

```java
    /**
     *
     * @param docBuff
     * @param foreignKeys
     * @param columnMap
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private void importedTag(StringBuilder docBuff, ResultSet foreignKeys, Map<String, Map<String, String>> columnMap) throws SQLException {
        /*
            PKTABLE_CAT String => primary key table catalog being imported (may be null)
            PKTABLE_SCHEM String => primary key table schema being imported (may be null)
            PKTABLE_NAME String => primary key table name being imported
            PKCOLUMN_NAME String => primary key column name being imported
            FKTABLE_CAT String => foreign key table catalog (may be null)
            FKTABLE_SCHEM String => foreign key table schema (may be null)
            FKTABLE_NAME String => foreign key table name
            FKCOLUMN_NAME String => foreign key column name
            KEY_SEQ short => sequence number within a foreign key( a value of 1 represents the first column of the foreign key, a value of 2 would represent the second column within the foreign key).
            UPDATE_RULE short => What happens to a foreign key when the primary key is updated:
                importedNoAction - do not allow update of primary key if it has been imported
                importedKeyCascade - change imported key to agree with primary key update
                importedKeySetNull - change imported key to NULL if its primary key has been updated
                importedKeySetDefault - change imported key to default values if its primary key has been updated
                importedKeyRestrict - same as importedKeyNoAction (for ODBC 2.x compatibility)
            DELETE_RULE short => What happens to the foreign key when primary is deleted.
                importedKeyNoAction - do not allow delete of primary key if it has been imported
                importedKeyCascade - delete rows that import a deleted key
                importedKeySetNull - change imported key to NULL if its primary key has been deleted
                importedKeyRestrict - same as importedKeyNoAction (for ODBC 2.x compatibility)
                importedKeySetDefault - change imported key to default if its primary key has been deleted
            FK_NAME String => foreign key name (may be null)
            PK_NAME String => primary key name (may be null)
            DEFERRABILITY short => can the evaluation of foreign key constraints be deferred until commit
                importedKeyInitiallyDeferred - see SQL92 for definition
                importedKeyInitiallyImmediate - see SQL92 for definition
                importedKeyNotDeferrable - see SQL92 for definition


         */
        String primaryCatalog = null;
        String primaryModel = null;
        String primaryTable = null;
        String primaryColumn = null;
        String foreignCatalog = null;
        String foreignModel = null;
        String foreignTable = null;
        String foreignColumn = null;
        String columnType = null;
        short keySequence = 0;

        primaryCatalog = foreignKeys.getString("PKTABLE_CAT");
        primaryModel = foreignKeys.getString("PKTABLE_SCHEM");
        primaryTable = foreignKeys.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
        primaryColumn = foreignKeys.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");

        foreignCatalog = foreignKeys.getString("FKTABLE_CAT");
        foreignModel = foreignKeys.getString("FKTABLE_SCHEM");
        foreignTable = foreignKeys.getString("FKTABLE_NAME");
        foreignColumn = foreignKeys.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");

        columnType = columnMap.get(foreignColumn).get(TYPE_NAME);


        keySequence = foreignKeys.getShort(KEY_SEQ);

        foreignTag(docBuff, primaryCatalog, primaryModel, primaryTable, primaryColumn, foreignCatalog, foreignModel, foreignTable, foreignColumn, keySequence, columnType);
    }
```

Comment: The DatabaseMetaData class has a getImportedKey method that should give you access to read primary and foreign keys. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html#object-databasemetadata. What are you getting when you call that class's method?

Comment: _"The database has the RI created"_ what does "RI" mean?

Comment: Referential Integrity.  e.g. foreign keys.

Comment: @GregPavlik You can see that my code calls getImportedKeys.  It is returning nothing when the foreign keys are disabled.